# How to formalize this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following claim, and I believe I have a proof.

**Claim**: If the system $Ax\leq b$ has a solution, then $b$ can be written as $u+v$, where $u \in \text{Im}(A)$ and $v \geq 0$.

**Proof**: Consider the following decomposition of $b$ into the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^m$, scaled by the vector $c$: $b=c_1e_1+c_2e_2 + \dots c_me_m$. This can be rewritten using the matrix $I_m$.

$$
   b=  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & 1
   \end{bmatrix} 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   c_1 \\
   \vdots \\
   c_m
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Now, let $c^{+}$ be the vector obtained by replacing any negative coordinate in $c$ with $0$, and $c^-$ be the vector obtained by replacing any positive coordinate in $c$ with $0$. Clearly, $c^{+}+c^-=c$. Now, let $u=I_mc^-$ and $v=I_mc^{+}$. We have $u+v=b$, since $I_mc^-+I_mc^{+}=I_m(c^-+c^+)=I_mc=b$. By construction, $v$ is strictly greater than $0$, so all that is left to show is that $u \in \text{Im}(A)$. Since $Ax\leq b$, $b$ cannot be negative in the direction of any basis vector $e_i$ if $e_i \notin \text{Im}(A)$, because if $e_i$ were not in the image of $A$, then the smallest magnitude the vector $Ax$ could have in the direction of $e_i$ is $0$. Thus, if $b$ is negative in the direction of $e_i$, and $Ax \leq b$, then we must have $e_i \in \text{Im}(A)$. Since $c^-$ captures only the negative magnitudes in the basis-vector decomposition of $b$, it must be that $u \in \text{Im}(A)$.
**QED**

This proof seems pretty hand-wavy to me, specifically the argument I make about $b$ having negative magnitude in the "direction" of basis vectors. Does anyone have any thoughts about how I could formalize this notion and approach it in a more structured, algebraic, way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $A$ does not necessarily have anything to do with the standard basis $\{e_i\}$. Indeed, it is possible for none of the standard basis vectors to be in the image of $A$ even if that image has dimension $m-1$ (the image might be the set of vectors orthogonal to $(1,\dots,1)$, for example).

To solve the problem, it suffices to let $x_0$ be a solution to $Ax\le b$, and consider $Ax_0 + (b-Ax_0)$.

In general, I find it more effective to avoid specifying bases (even the standard basis) whenever possible; and when I do need to specify a basis, I'd rather specify a basis having to do with the matrix involved (its eigenvectors, for example).

Comment: Thank you! Considering $Ax_0 + (b-Ax_0)$ is a very simple solution that I overlooked.